# Forcing a rerun of a module's install script

Tags: 8, configuration

I use configuration synchronization to synchronize my different environments, and I enabled `Ultimate Cron` on my local environment and then ran my sync scripts to synchronize my Staging environment.

My staging environment has Ultimate Cron enabled now, however I can't do anything with it because I keep getting the error:

```
Base table or view not found: XXXX Table 'my_staging_db.ultimate_cron_log' doesn't exist: INSERT INTO ...
```

It seems the install script wasn't ran correctly during the sync and so I'm missing the proper tables it creates. Unfortunately this means I can't uninstall the module either, therefore I can't reinstall it. I tried to run `drush devel:reinstall ultimate_cron` but of course that just runs `drush pm:uninstall ultimate_cron` so that command fails as well.

The Ultimate Cron's install script contains a `hook_schema` method defining the schema, so I was hoping there was someway to replicate that method so that I can copy the schema and insert it into the DB so that I can properly uninstall and reinstall the module to get the correct settings.

How can I approach fixing this issue?

Comment: add the ultimate_cron module to your **core.extension.yml** file like under module key like *ultimate_cron: 0* change the 0 with the weight you want so like that when you import your config in your dev env the ultimate_cron will be installed

Comment: What weight would be the one I want to change it to? Not sure what that means

Comment: added it to the end of the line under module key and give it the last module weight plus one for example if you found for example last line is **paragraphs: 11**  so add after it **ultimate_cron: 12**